# Assigning random values to a pair of integers using rpois(2,100)

Tags: r, random, integer, poisson

Let's say I have two integers which are (x, y). How do I assign the values of (x, y) to rpois(2,100)? I need to do this because I need to change the values of (x, y) randomly all the time to test my functions if they are correct. I tried to use:

```
=function(x, y) {
(x, y)=rpois(2,100)
return(x, y)
}
```

However, it appears that (x, y) is wrong because of the comma

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to Mossa's answer, this should get something like what you want:

```
mult <- with(as.list(xy <- setNames(rpois(2, 100), c("x", "y"))), LCM(x, y))
```

Running this will result in two objects in your environment: `xy` will be an integer vector of length 2 with names "x" and "y". `mult` is the output of your `LCM` function with the values of `xy` passed as arguments.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
xy <- rpois(2, 100)
x <- xy[1]
y <- xy[2]
mult <- LCM(x, y)
```

or

```
xy <- rpois(2, 100)
mult <- LCM(xy[1], xy[2])
```

Either of which are probably more readable code.

UPDATE in response to comment:

`xy` is your x and y, and it is available after you call `LCM`. Demonstrated with the `Lcm` function from the `pracma` package:

```
library(pracma)

> mult <- with(as.list(xy <- setNames(rpois(2, 100), c("x", "y"))), Lcm(x, y))
> print(paste("LCM of", xy[1], "and", xy[2], "is", mult))
[1] "LCM of 95 and 91 is 8645"
> mult <- with(as.list(xy <- setNames(rpois(2, 100), c("x", "y"))), Lcm(x, y))
> print(paste("LCM of", xy[1], "and", xy[2], "is", mult))
[1] "LCM of 103 and 102 is 10506"
> mult <- with(as.list(xy <- setNames(rpois(2, 100), c("x", "y"))), Lcm(x, y))
> print(paste("LCM of", xy[1], "and", xy[2], "is", mult))
[1] "LCM of 104 and 109 is 11336"
```

If you are trying to test `LCM` it would probably be easiest to do the following since the results of `rpois` are uncorrelated. Say you wanted to test 100 pairs of `x`, `y`:

```
xy <- matrix(rpois(200, 100), ncol = 2)
mult <- LCM(xy[,1], xy[,2])
```

Now `xy` is a 100 by 2 matrix where each row is a `x`, `y` pair and `mult` is the LCM. This will work if `LCM` is vectorized. If it is not vectorized, simply call `Vectorize(LCM)` before running the two lines of code above.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the help. Truly appreciate it but I have just one problem. It always gives me the same value of LCM. Why cant it generate a random value of LCM everytime I run mult <- LCM(x,y). For example, it seems that rpois(2,100) always seem to generate the same pair of integers.  Secondly it gives me the final value which is the LCM but I kinda need to know the value of x,y beforehand because I need to state the pair of integers generated from rpois(2,100) in my report but I cant seem to figure the pair of integers if it just straightaway gave the value of LCM immediately.

Comment: @user17233361 See the updated answer. Does that help?

Comment: Alright Thank you, This works wonders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assumming that you want `x ~ Pois(2)` and `y ~ Pois(100)`.
This means that you actually want

```r
> xy <- rpois(n = 2, lambda = c(2, 100))
> xy
[1]   4 119
```

So now, if you do `rpois(n = 100, lambda = c(2, 100))` then half of these entries
will be with `Pois(2)` and the other half `Pois(100)`, alternating in the resulting numeric.

Then you can assign: `x <- xy[1]` and `y <- xy[2]`.
There is no "tuple assignment" in R, although the `{zealot}` package attempts at providing such a functionality.

### Addendum

For completion: Note that you can use pattern indexing to access the alternating values:

```r
xy_n <- rpois(n = 2 * 100, lambda = c(2, 100))
x <- xy_n[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
y <- xy_n[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
```

Comment: Hi,I believe that you misunderstood what I wanted but that is probably due to my poor phrasing of the question and my horrendous code which made no sense. Okay, let me give you the backstory. I made a function to find the Least common multiple of two positive integers. The two positive integers are labeled (x,y). However, I need to find a way to assign the value of rpois(2,100) to x and y. This is because  I need to generate random values for my positive integer (x,y) and the question said that it must be done using rpois(2,100). So how do I input values of x,y in  LCM=function(x,y){....}